# GAS retrieve spreadsheet array in HTML service

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to retrieve a row from a spreadsheet and append it as an html element when a button is pushed.  Any advice on why my code isn't working? I tried this - [Retrieve cell date from a google spreadsheet to HTML service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19740301/retrieve-cell-date-from-a-google-spreadsheet-to-html-service) -solution earlier, but I may not have implemented it correctly. Thanks.

Index.html

```
<div id='vendordiv'>
      <p>
      <select>
        <option vlaue='abc'>abc</option>
        <option vlaue='xyz'>xyz</option>
      </select>
      </p>
      <p>
      <input type="Button" value="Get Rows"     onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(add_rows).rowArray()"/>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id ='transdiv'>

    </div>

    <script>

    function add_rows(rowArray) {

     var parent = document.getElementById('transdiv');
     var child = document.createElement('p');
     var text = rowArray[1];
       child.innerHTML = text;
       parent.appendChild(child);
}
</script>
```

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function rowArray() {
var ssID = "1pYBdbrCQWrY9haQP-d2G8GrytUJdtHLVLSOth02IwUc";
var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("APAll");
return sourceSheet.getDataRange();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your rowArray function, you are returning a Range object rather than the values themselves. 
The range represents the cells you are dealing with, but you must call getValues() to return an array of the cell contents.

```
function rowArray() {
    var ssID = "1pYBdbrCQWrY9haQP-d2G8GrytUJdtHLVLSOth02IwUc";
    var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("APAll");
    return sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
}
```

See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange()
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()